# How to install Mysql 8 to ubuntu without interaction?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, mysql-8.0

I want to install mysql 8 in silent mode.

So I want just to execute commands with parameters and see installed mysql 8 installed

Actually I use basic puppet config, it is dirty, but may be related to question

```
  exec { 'mysql-download':
    command     => 'wget -c https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb',
    path        => '/usr/bin',
    require     => Exec['apt-get -y update'],
  }->
  exec { 'mysql-dpkg':
    command     => 'sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb',
    path        => '/usr/bin',
    require     => [Exec['apt-get -y update'], Exec['mysql-download']],
  }->
  exec { 'mysql-apt-get -y update':
    command     => 'sudo apt-get -y update',
    path        => '/usr/bin',
    require     => [Exec['apt-get -y update'], Exec['mysql-dpkg']],
  }

  package { 'mysql-server':
    ensure  => 'present',
    require => Exec['apt-get update'],
  }
```